# Knockout Custom Binding Handler - Load Template and Display Popover

Tags: knockout.js, popover

I am trying to create a dynamic popover from data in my knockout view model.  I am working on writing a custom binding handler that loads a template for each of the items in the array.

Here is the start of my binding handler.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.notificationsPopover = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        console.log('init called');
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        console.log('update called');
        console.log(value);

        var notifications = $("<div>");

        $.each(value, function () {
            console.log(ko.toJS(this));
            var data = this;
            var elm = $("<div>");

            ko.renderTemplate('Notification', data, {
                afterRender: function (nodes) {
                    notifications.append(elm.html());
                    console.log("Called");
                }
            }, elm.get(0), "replaceChildren");
        });

        var options = {
            title: 'Notifications',
            html: true,
            content: "'" + notifications.html() + "'",            
            placement: 'bottom'
        };
        $(element).popover(options);
        console.log(notifications.html());
    }
};
```

In the console I see the update is getting called twice.  Once with no data and a second time when the data has been loaded into the array that this element is bound with.  It appears though my afterRender is only being called once and at that time the notifications.html() contains:

```
<div class="infuser-loading">Loading...</div>
```

My template looks as follows:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        <img data-bind="attr: { src: senderphoto(), alt: sendername() }" />
    </div>
    <div class="span9">
        <p data-bind="html: message()"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get this to load the template for each item in the array and then use those templates concatenated together as the content for the popover?

Comment: Is your template id named 'Notification'?

Comment: Yes.  I am using the knockout external template engine, I have a template file called 'Notification'.  Interestingly enough, I just tried to refresh the page a few times and it appears that once the template has been loaded it works.  So my issue now appears to be that 'afterRender' is being called before the template is loaded.

Comment: Got the same problem, saw somewhere that afterRender used to be called twice, once for the loading template and once after the actual template was loaded, but now that doesn't seem to happen.